# Retrofit 2.0: How to map objects with different type

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap, retrofit2

This is my sample JSON Response:

```
{
"success": true,
"details": {
    "banners": [
        {
            "banner_id": "1",
            "file_id": "368",
            "title": "INANG KALIKASAN'S BAD HAIR DAY",
            "description": "Et aeterno partiendo his, vim ponderum abhorreant et. Eum debet recusabo repudiandae in.",
            "created": "2018-03-09 07:56:04",
            "modified": "2018-04-02 09:59:54",
            "deleted": "",
            "file_name": "https://globegfs.imgix.net/uploads/2018-04-02/8a90371e9ad33cf06848b354b1fbd795.jpg",
            "orig_file_name": "hero-1.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "recent_books": [
        {
            "content_id": "353",
            "category_id": "24",
            "title": "One Hundred Fourth Symphony, in D-major",
            "author": "Franz Josef Haydn",
            "description": "The last of the 12 London Symphonies written by Franz Haydn. This ebook contains copies of the 4 movements in .mid format.",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "content_id": "353",
                    "tag_id": "14",
                    "created": "2018-04-27 15:57:46",
                    "tag_name": "Ray Collections"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "classics": [
        {
            "content_id": "353",
            "category_id": "24",
            "title": "One Hundred Fourth Symphony, in D-major",
            "author": "Franz Josef Haydn",
            "description": "The last of the 12 London Symphonies written by Franz Haydn. This ebook contains copies of the 4 movements in .mid format.",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "content_id": "353",
                    "tag_id": "14",
                    "created": "2018-04-27 15:57:46",
                    "tag_name": "Ray Collections"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Only the `banners` object has a different list of contents. All the succeeding Json Elements will have the same contents but in a list, having its Json Node its actual `title`. How can I map this into a HashMap?

I figured it will look something like this:

```
private List<GFSBannerResponse> banners;
private List<HashMap<String, List<GFSContentResponse>>> featuredContent;
```

but I still don't have an idea on how to implement this. I am using Retrofit 2.0 and Gson.

Comment: you can use jsonschema to pojo which will manage your response and generate related model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing it this way:

```
@SerializedName("details")
@Expose
private JsonElement details;
```

I just used `JsonParser` to parse the content to a `JsonElement`. Stuck with `GSON` for all of this, although this wasn't the ideal implementation. Will try to implement a custom Deserializer in the future.